# EM-wave energy of the Gaussian laser beam

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves

I am trying to calculate EM-energy store in a [Gaussian beam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam) as

$U_{EM} = \epsilon_0 \int_V d^3r \vec{E} \cdot \vec{E}^{\dagger}$

What I get is $U_{EM} \propto (\pi A^2/2)*\infty$ because of integration over $z$. What is the consistent way of defining the EM-energy stored in an optical beam?

Thanks in advance for help!

---

Let's consider the Gauss beam as:

$\vec{E} = \frac{\vec{A}}{\text{w}(z)} e^{-\frac{\rho^2}{\text{w}^2(z)}}e^{\frac{ik\rho^2}{2R(z)}}$

Explicit evaluation:

$\int_V d^3r \vec{E} \cdot \vec{E}^{\dagger} = 2\pi A^2 \int_0^{\infty} dz \frac{1}{\text{w}^2(z)} \int_0^{\infty}d\rho \;\rho \; e^{-\frac{2\rho^2}{\text{w}^2}} = \int_0^{\infty}dz \frac{2\pi A^2\text{w}^2(z)}{4 \text{w}^2(z)}=\frac{\pi A^2}{2}\int_0^{\infty}dz=\infty$

I guess the beam cannot propagate to infinity... Makes sense. How do I define EM energy though in an unambiguous way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you get an infinite energy when integrating
from $z=0$ to $\infty$. This is no surprise.
The laser needs to shine for an infinite time
to reach $z=\infty$, and therefore has emitted infinite energy.

It would make more sense to calculate the energy *per length*
(let's say from $z=0$ to $L$):
$$\begin{align}
\frac{U_{EM}}{L}
 &= \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0\frac{1}{L} \int_V d^3r \vec{E} \cdot \vec{E}^{\dagger} \\
 &= \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0\frac{2\pi A^2}{L} \int_0^L dz \frac{1}{\text{w}^2(z)} \int_0^{\infty}d\rho \;\rho \; e^{-\frac{2\rho^2}{\text{w}^2}} \\
 &= \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0\frac{1}{L} \int_0^Ldz \frac{2\pi A^2\text{w}^2(z)}{4 \text{w}^2(z)} \\
 &= \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0\frac{\pi A^2}{2L}\int_0^Ldz \\
 &= \epsilon_0\frac{\pi A^2}{4}
\end{align}$$

Comment: As I pointed out in my answer, the actual energy per unit length would be half that value, because the time-averaged energy density is $\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0|\vec{E}|^2$.

Comment: @Puk You're right. I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are working in frequency domain (i.e. $\vec{E}$ is a phasor), the average energy stored within a volume is half of the integral in your question. It should not be evaluating to zero as the integrand is non-negative. You probably made a mistake in your integration. You may need to show your work if you need more help.

Update:

Looks like you were getting infinity as the result, not zero. This is expected. After you turn on a laser beam, every second you wait, you are adding more energy to the resulting electromagnetic field distribution, at a more or less constant rate. The field expression you are using extends to infinity along the z-axis: this is the expression you get when the laser has been on for an infinitely long time, so you would expect the energy integral to diverge.

In practice the field distribution is different either because the beam has been on for a finite amount of time (and hence does not extend to infinity), or it is obstructed/scattered by other things.

Comment: thanks for your response! See the updated question, pls.